# Editing array type attributes in attribute table

Tags: qgis, postgresql, attribute-table, array, integer

I loaded a PostgreSQL layer in QGIS project. The layer has some array type attributes like `integer[]`.

I'd like to edit these attributes in Attribute Table. But it doesn't work, I could not type any value in the table cell.

I also tried changing the Fields Widget of the attribute but it seem doesn't support multidimensional array value.

Comment: Array types are a non-relational extension of PG. Implementing them would be a significant change to the ODBC model used in cursors. It's not really a surprise they're not supported. I suggest you use the relational model and implement the lists as one-to-many tables.

Comment: Which version are you using? Editing an `integer[]` field should work out of the box (QGIS 3.10)

Comment: @JGH I am currently using QGIS 3.12.1. I have not done this on QGIS 3.10 before. I may have a try, thanks.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for your explanation. But using one-to-many tables is too complicated for editing features manually. Strange thing is if I export features as a GeoJSON file. The list-like string will automatically convert to list type. If I import the GeoJSON , the list turns to string. They don't support array types may have other reasons other than ODBC model.

Answer (score 2):

For a table containing an array of integer

```
 create table testarr(id int primary key, arr integer[], geom geometry(point, 4326));
```

The widget type should be set to `list`

[image]

You can then edit a current record

[image]

or add a new one

[image]

Comment: Yes, this way works, but it doesn't support more than 1 dimension array :(